# Did Yoda live on a hill?

Tags: character, star-wars

I had the following dialogue with my mother this morning, which took an unexpected turn

> Me: All this time gone by and only now do I find out that Yoda has a surname, it's Layheehoo
>   Her: Oh, that's funny because he lives on a hill

Now, my mother has always been a bit of a left-handed monkey-wrench, but did she just make this up off the top of her head, as she does with many things, or **is there any evidence that Yoda did actually live on a hill?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this a joke only vaguely related to movies.

Comment: The message I sent to my mother was a joke, but my question is about the accuracy of her reply

Comment: It's still asking to explain a joke. The movie aspect is irrelevant,

Comment: I disagree. I'm not asking to explain a joke. I get the joke. I'm asking if there is any evidence of Yoda living on a hill. I thought that was made quite clear in not only the subject line of the post, but also the question body, maybe if I put it in bold it would help?

Comment: i don't know where you got Layheehoo from, the only time i ever saw that was in an answer on [SciFi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135843/what-is-yodas-full-name) which had no citation and has since been deleted

Comment: @Memor-X it was a joke and was not relevant to the question, I only added the joke itself as a bit of background to explain why I was asking the question

Comment: It seems pretty relevant to the problem since the entire question's premise foots on nothing but a joke that for everything we know, could just be entirely made-up nonsense. If I think Indiana Jones would play a mean balalaika, do you want me to ask if he actually *can* play balalaika?

Comment: It seems no one asked: why don't you ask your mother herself where she got this notion.  Why would you ask us?  You have access to the source.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe her reply was just an addition to your (funny!) joke, and not based on anything in the movies.

In your joke, you say that Yoda's full name is pronounced as though he's yodeling. Yodeling comes from the Alps, which are mountainous. Your mom quickly made this association, and said "he lives on a hill".

Hill = Alps = birthplace of yodeling

.

*And that, readers, is how I ruin humor through analysis. :-)*

Comment: My kind of party ruiner.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm going to have to counter your point. [(Over)analysis does not always ruin humor.](https://what-if.xkcd.com/)

Comment: I understood the reference to hills, I just was unsure if there was ever any reference to Yoda living on a hill or if her response was entirely fabricated. The first line of your answer answers my question perfectly, I'll hold off on accepting to give others a chance at refuting it

Comment: Dose his cushy chair on the Jedi Council count as a little hill? :P

Comment: @DarrenH Fair enough!

Comment: Essentially, the mother is actually referencing the origins of the joke which is a song - https://genius.com/Richard-rodgers-lonely-goatherd-lyrics

Comment: @Paulie_D THAT'S THE ANSWER! I've seen the movie and play many many times, and I didn't put that together. (To be fair, there are a lot of songs in it, so I can't remember the lyrics to every one.)

Answer (score 4):

The area near Yoda's hut/hole in the ground is depicted as a densely vegetated swamp/bog/marsh.  That's why Luke's ship is stuck in the muck.

Swamps/wetlands are generally located in low-lying areas, which fits Yoda's location more than the Alps. I think your mom was just riffing on your joke, not actually making an accurate reference.